# Azure Batch pool of VMs and on-premises Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-batch

Can VMs from the pool of Azure Batch service be joined to on-premises Active Directory while executing the jobs so that they can access on-premises resources and data stores?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible by bringing your own Azure Virtual Network (i.e., you specify the virtual network to deploy your pool to) and using a [VPN Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways). Specifically, [ARM VNet site-to-site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal) or [Classic VNet site-to-site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-classic-portal) depending upon if you have a ARM VNet with a VirtualMachineConfiguration Batch pool or a Classic VNet with a CloudServiceConfiguration Batch pool, respectively.